# Expanded clickable area not working in Firefox

Tags: css, accessibility, pseudo-element

Since pseudo-elements capture mouse clicks, I'm trying to create an expanded clickable area for a button using an absolutely-positioned ::after element:

```css
button {
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: -12px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<button>
    Go
</button>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, and Edge, but not in Firefox (Mac or Windows). Any ideas why?

Comment: It works the same in Chrome and Firefox for me. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: works for me on all browsers too

Comment: i'm still using firefox 56 b/c newer versions don't work with jaws yet, but in ff56, i see the problem.  i can click on the blue button but cannot click in the area between the blue button and the red outline. perhaps it works in newer versions of ff.  it works fine in chrome.  in ie11, the red outline does not appear.

Comment: When I say it's not working, I mean that clicking outside the button, but inside the red outline, does not fire the click event. You also don't see the "pointer" cursor in that expanded area. In non-Firefox browsers, hovering this area shows the pointer and clicking this area fires the click event. I'm using Firefox 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using a `div` inside your button instead of adding a pseudo-element

```css
div {
    background-color: darkblue;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px;
}
button {
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <div>Go</div>
</button>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you, Adam. It's still a mystery why the pseudo-element solution doesn't work in Firefox. *Shrugs shoulders*